# GAE Model Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module

These are the modules I'm importing

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import db
```

This is where my code uses Model (and receives an error)

```
#class_checking = Class_checking(id = classname) --> how i created Object
#......#
#class_c_prereq is the key_name that was made manually 
class_c_update = Model.get_by_key_name(class_c_prereq)
#I need to retrieve the entity, but Model is undefined
```

This is the traceback error

```
File "C:\Users\Desktop\classes\main.py", line 59, in post
self.updating(class_data)
File "C:\Users\Desktop\classes\main.py", line 40, in updating
class_c_update =Model.get_by_key_name(class_c_prereq)
NameError: global name 'Model' is not defined
```

A Class_checking entity is created by this:

```
class_checking = Class_checking(classC_name = classname, classC_prereq = prereq, classC_point_To = 0, classC_point_By = 1, classC_array = class_data_JSON, id = classname )
```

I then have a separate function that is meant to update the attribute  classC_point_To

```
class_data = Class_checking.query().fetch() #gets all entities of Class
for class_c1 in class_data: 
    class_c_prereq = class_c1.classC_prereq #gets the class prereq, only 1 prereq
    for prereq_class in class_data: #loop through all entities of Class
        if prereq_class.classC_name == class_c_prereq: #if the class name == prereq
            class_c_update = db.Model.get_by_key_name(class_c_prereq) #update the class name so that it "points to" a class
            class_c_update.classC_point_To = 1
            class_c_update.put()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the model subclass to fetch the data by key. In your example your model is `Class_checking` so the correct classmethod would be `Class_checking.get_by_key_name(class_c_prereq)` for `db.Model` subclasses and `Class_checking.get_by_id(class_c_prereq)` for a `ndb.Model` subclass.

Comment: class_c_update = Class_checking.get_by_key_name(class_c_prereq) **But then I get this error**
       AttributeError: type object 'Class_checking' has no attribute    'get_by_key_name'

Comment: Is `Class_checking` an `ndb.Model`? Don't mix `db` and `ndb` code if you don't have to.

Comment: I did not realize the difference between db and ndb. I ended up using *get_by_id*. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference db in this case.

Use:

```
class_c_update = db.Model.get_by_key_name(...)
```

or

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import Model
```

Comment: class_c_update = db.Model.get_by_key_name(class_c_prereq) **But then I get this error** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'classC_point_To'   (I checked online and NoneType means that it really didn't get the object, but based on the documentation, I can retrieve entities based on their ID, which i explicitly created for each entity)